# how to link contact with facebook, gmail etc?

Tags: contacts, cyanogenmod

I am on cm7 & HTC Desire. Old HTC Sence was linking my contacts with Facebook, Gmail etc. It gave me good suggestions what could be linked or an easy way how to link a contact item with some other kind of account. The current contact manager has a 'join' feature which I am not sure if I can use for Facebook.

Are there any advanced contact managers?

Answer (score 4):

You have to go to `Edit contact`, then press the Menu key, then select `Join`. This gives you the list of suggested contacts to join. Works for me between Google contacts and Facebook on Galaxy S + CyanogenMod 7.1.

Answer (score 3):

If you're only looking to have your contacts' display images synced with their Facebook avatars, I recommend you take a look at the freeware [SyncMyPix](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.nloko.android.syncmypix) - it's a little unwieldy but tends to do the job.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Join feature to merge Facebook contacts as well.

Comment: how? :-) If I select join I would expect facebook, gmail etc accounts from the same person to be in some kind of list so I can select. And that's it. Like it was in Sence. I really do not know how to do it now...

Comment: They should be suggested, but only if your phone has a clear way of matching them (exact same name, same email, etc).  You should be able to click a contact, choose Join, then find and click the contact you want to join (even when it doesn't provide the short list of possibilities).

Comment: it doesn't tell you what kind of contact it is. It might be an old already non existing email address. Or how can I link the contact with facebook?

Comment: Hmm, mine has a little icon beside each contact's name that indicates where it's from.  But I'm not on CM7, so maybe it doesn't have that.