# How can I force-link a Google contact with a Facebook profile?

Tags: contacts, sync, facebook

Back when my HTC Desire had its stock Sense, there was an option to link Facebook accounts to Google contacts, by selecting them from the Facebook friends list.

This created fields for my contacts such as:

```
<HTCData>
<Facebook>id:02394985720/friendof:2103910923|id:123768123/friendof:09812387</Facebook>   
</HTCData>
```

Now, my phone is on CyanogenMod 7. I've added a Facebook account under Synchronization settings, but it seems it only matches contacts who have the same name as their Facebook counterpart. Those who are matched get a Facebook profile link:

[image]

The other ones aren't linked. Therefore: **How can I force link a Google contact with a Facebook profile?** This would allow me to link contacts even if their names are different.

<sub>I'm aware of this question: [how to link contact with facebook, gmail etc?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6874/how-to-link-contact-with-facebook-gmail-etc), but there is no "Join" option for me, and it isn't really answered as well. I'm also aware of [SyncMyPix](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.nloko.android.syncmypix).</sub>

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13533/how-can-i-merge-contacts-in-cyanogenmod/29153#29153

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, in the Facebook app, under its Settings, enable synchronization for all contacts.

Open up your contact list and select the Google contact you would like to merge. Then push the menu button and select "Edit Contact". Then hit the menu button one more time and select "Join".

Choose which contact you would like to merge it with and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 3):

For those using Sense, you also can add the link manually (I found that Sense doesn't always add the notes tag to Google Contacts automatically). You can get the Facebook "id" by going to `graph.facebook.com/username` instead of `www.facebook.com/username` (i.e. after you click on a friend on the Facebook webpage, replace "www" with "graph"). Then just paste into Google Contacts notes:

```
<HTCData><Facebook>id:12345/friendof:67890</Facebook></HTCData>
```

where `12345` is your friend's id and `67890` is your id.

Sense picks up the link on the next sync with Google Contacts and the Facebook link is added permanently.

Answer (score 0):

FOr making this process simpler, use go contacts. One click joining. Just open go contacts and open the menu, at the menu click on merge, it would give you sort options. Sort based on name, email and phone number. Choose an option and it would cluster the contacts it feels are duplicates together and ask you for confirmation. You can review and decide what to merge and what not to.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: Glad you asked, download go contacts, once you do this go to menu and you will have an option called merge. Here you will get options like merge by name, number, email etc. Then it will club all results and show, all you have to do is click on each contact once and they get merged.

Comment: This doesn't work at all. Neither criterion delivers any results. The problem is that the contacts I want to merge don't have the same name, and most Facebook contacts have no e-mail address or phone number given.

Comment: i spoke from my experience, i managed to merge most using go contacts and a few i merged manually using join. Sorry it din't work for you!

Comment: done ! I was just trying to tell you what i did hoping it would help.