# How can I merge contacts in CyanogenMod?

Tags: contacts, cyanogenmod

Can I merge contacts in CyanogenMod 7 like I was able to do in HTC Sense?

Let's that I have my contact 'John Smith', then I import contacts from Facebook and a new John Smith appeared. I want these two contacts to be merged under one single contact.

Can I do that somehow in CyanogenMod 7?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I force-link a Google contact with a Facebook profile?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13310/how-can-i-force-link-a-google-contact-with-a-facebook-profile)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Merge exists in CM 6 - edit the contact, select "join" - if it's not in 7, it's a regression.

Comment: Asker probably means *automatic* merging (or rather "linking"), which for example my Samsung's TouchWiz interface does.

Comment: Then OP needs to update their question. :)

Comment: Yup, very true. :)

Comment: Why do I need to update my question?

Comment: I still can't do it. Where can I find linking/join?

Answer (score 6):

It's also available in CM9: If you have selected "edit" for a contact, the overflow/context menu will show the "join" option.

[image]